# Speeding up Tensorflow 2.0 Gradient Tape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have been following the TF 2.0 tutorial for convolution VAE's, located [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/r2/tutorials/generative/cvae.ipynb).

Since it is eager, the gradients are computed by hand and then applied manually, using tf.GradientTape().

```py
for epoch in epochs:
  for x in x_train:
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
      loss = compute_loss(model, x)
    apply_gradients(tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables))
```

The problem with that code is that it is pretty slow, taking around 40-50 seconds per epoch.
If I increase the batch size by a lot (to around 2048), then it ends up taking around 8 seconds per epoch, but the model's performance decreases by quite a lot.

On the other hand, if I do a more traditional model (i.e., that uses the lazy graph-based model instead of eagerness), such as the one [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/variational_autoencoder_deconv.py), then it takes 8 seconds per epoch even with a small batch size.

```
model.add_loss(lazy_graph_loss)
model.fit(x_train epochs=epochs)
```

Based on this information, my guess would be that the problem with the TF2.0 code is the manual computation of losses and gradients.

Is there any way to speed up the TF2.0 code so that it comes closer to the normal code?

Comment: Hardly anyone will read tons of code from your links. Read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to improve your question.

Answer (score 7):

I found the solution: TensorFlow 2.0 introduces the concept of [functions](https://www.tensorflow.org/r2/guide/autograph), which translate eager code into graph code.

The usage is pretty straight-forward. The only change needed is that all relevant functions (like `compute_loss` and `apply_gradients`) have to be annotated with `@tf.function`.

Answer (score 3):

The main reason why your code is taking a long time is because when we use a normal pythonic for loop which does not have any tensor, the construction of the graph takes tremendous amount of time because intuitively we might think that the same graph for training might be getting re used at every iteration, but the graph constructed is actually a chain like structure where each node is the training subgraph, and the total no. Of nodes in that chain are equivalent to the no. Of iterations in the loop. In a nutshell tensorflow unwraps the iterations and then constructs the graph. So it employs lot of redundancy in terms of both space and time for the graph alone. It's so bad that, just to add two tensors repeatedly in a normal pythonic loop for like a billion times, it takes almost half hour.

To get around this problem, specifically in your case we can take the help of .repeat transformation in the tf.data.Datasets api, instead of writing

```
for i in range(epochs) :
```

We can write

```
For x in x_train.repeat(epochs) :
        Train here
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I am testing this one but, in my case, instead of having the whole training data `x_train` available, I am using a data generator which only yields batches of data, so I cannot apply the line of code above directly. Is there any workaround?