# Using python lists and numpy arrays in tensorflow function(using @tf.function annotation)

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am building a LSTM model and am using tensorflow to build custom training loops, so that I can train the LSTM network with varying sequence lengths.

The training loops were running but was really slow when compared to keras.fitgenerator. So I refered these links : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/30596 , [Speeding up Tensorflow 2.0 Gradient Tape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54968545/speeding-up-tensorflow-2-0-gradient-tape) .

So for my training function , i used @tf.function decorator , but I am facing problem when loss is getting calculated. Below is the code snippet

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

print("tensorflow version:",tf.__version__)
print("numpy version:",np.__version__)
print("python version:",sys.version)

tensorflow version: 2.1.0
numpy version: 1.18.5
python version: 3.6.7 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 28 2018, 19:44:12) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]

# Test data
test_data_ft=[[[1]*23,[2]*23],[[[3]*23,[4]*23,[5]*23]]]
test_data_lb=[[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]
# Network
optimizer_lstmnet=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
loss_lstmnet = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy
lstm_net =tf.keras.Sequential()
lstm_net.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32,return_sequences=False,input_shape=(None,23)))
lstm_net.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(3))
lstm_net.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('softmax'))
#Training function using tensorflow function
@tf.function
def step(data_ft,data_lb):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        for i in range(len(data_ft)):
            # This loop makes a forward pass for each sequence
            # reshape the input data. 23 is the feature size, -1 this is the sequence length, we keep it as it is, 1 is the batch size
            x=np.array(data_ft[i]).reshape(1,-1,23)
            x_tens = tf.convert_to_tensor(x,dtype=tf.float32)
            #Make the forward pass
            pred_y = (lstm_net(x_tens))
            # reshape the target label into size (1,3) where 3 is the number of classes
            y= np.array(data_lb[i]).reshape(1,3)
            y_tens=tf.convert_to_tensor(y,dtype=tf.float32)
            # Calculate the loss
            lstm_net_loss += tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(y_tens, pred_y)
                
        # Calculate loss gradient per batch
        lstm_gradients = tape.gradient((lstm_net_loss), lstm_net.trainable_variables)
        optimizer_lstmnet.apply_gradients(zip(lstm_gradients, lstm_net.trainable_variables))
        return(lstm_net_loss)
#Training loop
for i in range(5):#epochs
    step(test_data_ft,test_data_lb)
```

This is the error:

```
 TypeError: in converted code:

    <ipython-input-10-a4181119dd69>:15 step  *
        lstm_net_loss += tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(y_tens, pred_y)
    C:\Users\rgv1cob\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tf_2.2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\math_ops.py:927 r_binary_op_wrapper
        x = ops.convert_to_tensor(x, dtype=y.dtype.base_dtype, name="x")
    C:\Users\rgv1cob\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tf_2.2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py:1314 convert_to_tensor
        ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
    C:\Users\rgv1cob\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tf_2.2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\constant_op.py:317 _constant_tensor_conversion_function
        return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
    C:\Users\rgv1cob\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tf_2.2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\constant_op.py:258 constant
        allow_broadcast=True)
    C:\Users\rgv1cob\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tf_2.2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\constant_op.py:296 _constant_impl
        allow_broadcast=allow_broadcast))
    C:\Users\rgv1cob\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tf_2.2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\tensor_util.py:451 make_tensor_proto
        _AssertCompatible(values, dtype)
    C:\Users\rgv1cob\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tf_2.2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\tensor_util.py:331 _AssertCompatible
        (dtype.name, repr(mismatch), type(mismatch).__name__))

    TypeError: Expected float32, got <tensorflow.python.autograph.operators.special_values.Undefined object at 0x000002D692C857B8> of type 'Undefined' instead.
```

Any help would be great.
Note : Please ignore my environment name tf_2.2.0 , i use tensorflow 2.1.0

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to run the code to reproduce that error. But I found some misstakes: So you didn't define the values:

```py
lstm_pbu_loss
lstm_pbu
```

maybe this could be the reason for your error?

Best regards

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint. I have now corrected the code. But the error is same. You can see from the error code that the problem is in calculating the loss:
 <ipython-input-10-a4181119dd69>:15 step  *
        lstm_net_loss += tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(y_tens, pred_y)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I have to initialize the loss before using it, so this correction did the trick

```
def step(data_ft,data_lb):
    lstm_net_loss=0 # The initialization of the loss has to be there..
    ......
```

Any information on why this behavior happens would be helpful